# Very narrow table caption

Tags: tables, captions, acm

I don't know why the table caption is so narrow

[image]

The code is

```
\begin{table}[!t]
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{\textbf{Main characteristics of the simulated system.} The latencies assume 45nm process at 2.5GHz.}
    \label{sim-param}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.75in}p{2.6in}}
        \hline
        Processor   &  UltraSPARC-III ISA, 8-stage pipeline, out of order, 4-wide dispatch/retirement, 96-entry ROB, 32-entry LSQ, 16-entry store buffer, 2.5GHz, 45nm \\
        L1 caches    &  Split I/D, 64KB private, 2-way, 64B, LRU, write-through, 2-cycle hit latency, 32-entry MSHR\\
        L2 cache     &  8MB shared, unified, non-inclusive, 8-way, 64B, LRU, write-back, 10-cycle hit latency, 64-entry MSHR (instruction and data)\\
        Main memory      &  64GB, 60ns access latency, 4 memory controllers \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And the packages and headers are

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}

% Metadata Information
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{3}
```

Comment: This is not a MWE unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try to put the `caption` after the `tabular` environment ?

Comment: @V. Rossetto: Where exactly? You mean after `\end{tabular}`? Same result at the bottom of the table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `acmsmall` document class has its own way to build tabular material through the `\tbl` command with syntax

```
\tbl{<caption>}{<the table itself>}
```

(refer to Section **4.2. Tables** of the PDF document `acmsmall-guide` that comes in the `.zip` file containing the class and related example files).

A complete example with your table:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}

% Metadata Information
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
    \tbl{\textbf{Main characteristics of the simulated system.} The latencies assume 45nm process at 2.5GHz.\label{sim-param}}
    {\begin{tabular}{p{0.75in}p{2.6in}}
        \hline
        Processor   &  UltraSPARC-III ISA, 8-stage pipeline, out of order, 4-wide dispatch/retirement, 96-entry ROB, 32-entry LSQ, 16-entry store buffer, 2.5GHz, 45nm \\
        L1 caches    &  Split I/D, 64KB private, 2-way, 64B, LRU, write-through, 2-cycle hit latency, 32-entry MSHR\\
        L2 cache     &  8MB shared, unified, non-inclusive, 8-way, 64B, LRU, write-back, 10-cycle hit latency, 64-entry MSHR (instruction and data)\\
        Main memory      &  64GB, 60ns access latency, 4 memory controllers \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Using the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package, you get improved tables:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}

% Metadata Information
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \tbl{\textbf{Main characteristics of the simulated system.} The latencies assume 45nm process at 2.5GHz.\label{sim-param}}
    {\begin{tabular}{p{0.75in}p{2.6in}}
        \toprule
        Processor   &  UltraSPARC-III ISA, 8-stage pipeline, out of order, 4-wide dispatch/retirement, 96-entry ROB, 32-entry LSQ, 16-entry store buffer, 2.5GHz, 45nm \\
        L1 caches    &  Split I/D, 64KB private, 2-way, 64B, LRU, write-through, 2-cycle hit latency, 32-entry MSHR\\
        L2 cache     &  8MB shared, unified, non-inclusive, 8-way, 64B, LRU, write-back, 10-cycle hit latency, 64-entry MSHR (instruction and data)\\
        Main memory      &  64GB, 60ns access latency, 4 memory controllers \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]